# What is an aromatic cage and what does it do?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, proteins

Epigenetics, 2. ed, Chapter 3.6:

> Similarly, methylated lysine residues embedded in histone tails can be
>   read by “aromatic cages” present in chromodomains, or similar domains
>   (e.g., MBT, Tudor) contained within complexes that facilitate
>   downstream chromatin modulating events (see Ch. 7 [Patel 2014] for
>   structural insights

I understand it is something like a protein motif, but I cannot find a good definition using google.

Comment: googling "chromodomain aromatic cage" leads to this paper : "Epigenetic Virtues of Chromodomains" (Crit Rev Biochem Mol Biol. 2011 Dec; 46(6): 507–526.) which references "aromatic cage" as "Structure of the HP1 chromodomain bound to a lysine 9-methylated histone H3 tail." (Science. 2002;295:2080–2083.). See figure 3c in the first paper : " The peptide sits on the DNA minor groove, with its methyllysine inserted in the four-residue aromatic cage."

Comment: Sentence from same book: `...The chromodomain forms an aromatic cage that has been well documented as a specific binding pocket to methylated histone residues`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the structures in the [PHD-finger domain](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/PHD_Finger) and chromodomains. The aromatic amino acid residues form a cage like structure which covers and interacts with the methylated ammonium of lysine via a cation-pi interaction.

> The BPTF-PHD structures reveal the main characteristics of PHD fingers that can read H3K4me3. The binding occurs through an aromatic cage where a trimethyl ammonium group is stabilized by van der Waals and cation-–π interaction, which is similar to the ones observed in **chromodomain**, MBT, PWWP, and Tudor domains. This aromatic cage is composed of one Trp and three Tyr residues; and it has three faces and a 'lid' that is beyond the tip of H3K4me3. Subsequently determined structures of other fingers in complex with the H3K4me3 peptides show that the cage varies and can contain a combination of two to four aromatic and hydrophobic residues.

[image]
 ***<sup>[Margueron et al., 2009](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature08398)</sup>***

Comment: Interesting, so in the image on the left, the cage is supported in a 7-propeller fold, but it is also found in this minimal PHD-finger domain (eg 1WEN) which is much smaller. cool.